# How to add dependency one executable from other executable?

Tags: cmake

The dependency between libraries and libraries+executable could be managed via target_link_libraries. So if some library fails build - all dependent targets will not build.

I have another task: there are exist the library target, the executable test target (that provide test for library) and the main executable target with main logic.

I need that main executable target should be build only if build of the executable test target is not fails.

In other word I need set up dependency between two executables.

How I could achieve it? Could somebody provide an example?

Comment: What is wrond with [add_dependencies](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html) command?

Comment: @Tsyvarev, ok, thx. I thought that any command without prefix "target_" is obsolet and there are exists moderd way.

Comment: "Modern" CMake prefers **target-oriented** commands over "global" ones. Command `add_dependencies` is perfectly target-oriented, even with absence of `target_` prefix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing is a different stage in the CMake/Ctest/CPack suite, so you’re unlikely to find a way to conditionally compile/link an executable based on test results.

You can use [`add_dependencies`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html) to ensure that the test executable builds first, but that’s not the same as only producing a build product of the test runs successfully.

I recommend running your build followed by the test. Based on the return code of the test, you can choose whether or not to package the final product.

Comment: Am I understand correctly that I need add_custom_target that launch the tests and add_dependencies from this target?

Comment: I would solve this problem outside of the `CMakeFile.txt`. Perform a complete build. Run `make test` or however you invoke CTest, then run `make package` if the test run succeeds.

Comment: You need to define your tests with `add_test` and call `enqble_testing()` in your CMake files somewhere, then run `make test`.